# Custom permalink post type not include -2 behind

Tags: wordpress

I need help about custom permalink post type wordpress.

Now, I have a post with permarlink:

- domain.com/post-type/test
- domain.com/post-type/test-2

How can I setup format to:

- domain.com/post-type/test-%post-id%
- domain.com/post-type/test-%post-id% (not include -2 behind)

I've used a plugin:

- Custom Post Type Permalinks https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

But not working, can someone please help me, thanks !

Comment: `-2` added by wordpress permalink is default functionality and it happens when same permalink already exists. Its better to change new permalink manually

Comment: @NaveedRamzan At first, thanks for your help, I'm so happy, but friendly url for SEO and content is built by users so I can't force all users set the title not duplicate.

Comment: Then you may set custom pattern for permalink that attach tag in permalink

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Thanks for your recommend ! That's a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * unifying slug of the CPT by adding post id in the slug
 *
 * @param $slug
 * @param $post_id
 * @param $post_status
 * @param $post_type
 * @param $post_parent
 * @param $original_slug
 *
 * @return null|string|string[]
 */
function custom_permalink_slug_wp_unique_post_slug_callback( $original_slug, $slug, $post_id, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent ) {

    // her we have to mention which post type to support
    $support_post_type = array( 'post', 'book' );

    if ( in_array( $post_type, $support_post_type ) ) {
        $slug = $slug . '-' . $post_id;
    }

    return $slug;
}

add_filter( 'pre_wp_unique_post_slug', 'custom_permalink_slug_wp_unique_post_slug_callback', 100, 6 );
```

Copy the above code and paste it, In your child themes functions.php file.
I have tested this out and it's working fine for me

Comment: I'm so happy with your help, but the word "test" is not a word, it's a permalink. That's mean, I have two posts with the same name, but wordpress auto generate permalink for two posts are post-name and post-name-2. So, I need to remove -2 include behide permalink and replace with post-id. For all, thanks for your help, i will research more. Have a nice day :)

Comment: @NghiaPhan I have updated my answer kindly check back. This is working fine for me 


Do not forget to mention the list of CPT that you want to support into the array

Comment: Sorry for late reply, thank you for your enthusiasm, "pre_wp_unique_post_slug" is a hook in **Custom Post Type Permalinks** plugin ? I've added slug in $support_post_type and after that, I went to Permalink setting and press save it, but not working. I've tried to add new post, but not working too. Poor me :(

Comment: No `pre_wp_unique_post_slug` is a WP core Hook. Can you give me the code that you are using to create custom CPT?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', function( $slug, $post_id, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ) {
  if ( $post_type == 'post' && $slug != $original_slug )
    $slug = preg_replace( '#\-[0-9]+$#', '-' . $post_id, $slug );

  return $slug;
}, 10, 6 );
```